# Azure pipeline trigger regardless of paths includes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I am trying to force azure devops pipeline only to run when files in the `/foo/bar` directory are modified. However with the below yaml config, this azure pipeline will run for any files modified in the repo.... including ones outside of `/foo/bar`. Why is this?

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - bar
```

Comment: I had some commit in another directory outside `/foo/bar` and the pipeline would run. However, if there would be no changes on that outside directory the pipeline will not run. It is best practice to create a new feature branch for every pipeline-directory relation instead of applying changes in multiple directories (& pipelines) at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Please add exclude as follows:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - bar
    exclude:
    - '*'
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be `'*'`

Comment: Actually, I still have issues where the stages run when I commit code that lives outside of `bar` directory. For instance, `foo` is a sibling of `bar`. If I modify code in `foo` then the stages for `bar` yml run.